# How to convert each line of a file into list(sublist) in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am relatively new to groovy. I have been trying to read .txt file and convert each line into the list. I read the file and convert it into a list of lines. I need to convert each line into a list and iterate through each line to make bigger list.
Here is the sample code

```
 File file = new File("C:Roster1.txt")

    if( !file.exists() ) {
        println "File does not exist"
    } else {

        file.splitEachLine("\n"){string->
            string.each{r ->
            r = r.split(' ')
            println r}
        }
    }
```

I even tried to use 
def lines = file.readLines()
// this creates list of lines, but not the list of string contents in each lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
if(!file.exists()) {
    println "File does not exist"
}
else {
    (file as List).each {
        println it.split(' ')
    }
}
```

Comment: can I do this: def data    if(!file.exists()) {
    println "File does not exist"
}
else {
    (file as List).each {
       data = it.split(' ')
    }   I tried this but I could get only last line.

Comment: Also, I didn't actually get the list separated by commas -> [a b c]. I was hoping to get -> [a,b,c]. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, you'll only get the last line, you're resetting `data` every time...  try `def data = (file as List).collect { it.split(' ') }`...  No idea what you mean for the second bit...

Comment: Regarding the second bit, I was trying to show the example.

Comment: So if I plan to compare the items in the list to another items from different list should I be using data[]? Any hints on comparing sub list items to list items would be great.